# Shiny - observeEvent appears without click

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to develop an application with two buttons : 
1. Calculate 
2. Refresh

When I click on the button "Calculate", a second button appears. When I click on the second button, a sentence appears : "Le resultat est...". The button refresh clean the web page. Now the page is clean and only the two initial buttons appears : Calculate and Refresh.

If i click another time on the button Calculate, the sentence "Le resultat est..." appears without click on the second button.

Question : How can i do obtain the sentence "Le resultat est..." only after a click on the second button ?

Below my code :

```
library(shiny)
data_Modele <- deval_Shiny

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("runif", "Uniform"),
  actionButton("reset", "Clear"),
  uiOutput("plot")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  v <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$runif, {
    v$data <- round(runif(1, min=1, max=nrow(deval_Shiny)),digits = 0)

    output$Button<- renderUI({
    actionButton("button", "click me")
  })
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    v$data <- NULL
  }) 

  observeEvent(input$button, {
  output$Reponse <- renderText(paste0("Le resultat est :",v$data))
  })


  output$plot <- renderUI({
    if (is.null(v$data)) return()

    tagList(
     uiOutput("Button"),
     uiOutput("Reponse")
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

J.

Comment: You could have translated your french sentence to post your example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your `uiOutputs` to behave separately, I would suggest not to bind them together inside `output$plot`. So if you don't need them to be together, I would add a variable `show_response` to control whether you want to display the response or not.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("runif", "Uniform"),
  actionButton("reset", "Clear"),
  uiOutput("Button"),
  uiOutput("Reponse")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  v <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  show_response <- reactiveValues(state = FALSE)

  observeEvent(input$runif, {
    v$data <- round(runif(1, min = 1, max = 100), digits = 0)
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    v$data <- NULL
    show_response$state <- FALSE
  }) 

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    show_response$state <- TRUE
  })

  output$Button <- renderUI({
    req(v$data) 
    actionButton("button", "click me")
  })

  output$Reponse <- renderText({
    req(show_response$state)
    paste0("Le resultat est :", v$data)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shinyjs` and its `show` and `hide` functions:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

deval_Shiny <- mtcars
data_Modele <- deval_Shiny

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("runif", "Uniform"),
  actionButton("reset", "Clear"),br(),
  actionButton("button", "click me"),
  textOutput("Reponse")
)

server <- function(input, output){

  observe({
    hide("button")
    hide("Reponse")
  })

  v <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

  observeEvent(input$runif,{
    show("button")
    v$data <- round(runif(1, min=1, max=nrow(deval_Shiny)),digits = 0)
  })

  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    hide("button")
    hide("Reponse")
  }) 

  output$Reponse <- renderText(paste0("Le resultat est :",v$data))

  observeEvent(input$button, {
    show("Reponse")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]